# How do i set the Firewall Requirements in android

Tags: android, firewall, agora.io

I'm a bit new to Android, and i try to use the Agora.io to make a videoChat app. after i tried to do the code in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BXPg112Ceo
and nothing happend, i went to the Agora.io Quickstart Guide, and found that i need to change the Firewall Requirements that specified in https://docs.agora.io/en/Agora%20Platform/firewall

i have no idea how to do that. can someone explain to me what i'm suppose to do?

Comment: Android commonly has no firewall.

Comment: @eldar Did you get any solution? We are also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The firewall settings are with regard to your local wifi router and modem settings to ensure that Agora's packets don't get blocked by your local network.

If you are struggling to get the Android SDK working you can checkout my tutorial
https://medium.com/agora-io/1-to-1-video-chat-app-on-android-using-agora-io-3c2fe6c42fb4

and also I've posted a simple working demo to GitHub using Android and the Agora.io Video SDK
https://github.com/digitallysavvy/android-video-chat-demo